# How to filter off a blank array? React/Javascript/Es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, foreach

I'm trying to filter through an array. I did a useEffect where it stores each object passed into it's own state. This includes the default `useState([])` blank array. I'm trying to make a function to remove it. This is the function:

```
const checker = [null, undefined, [{}], {},[],''];

    const filterredArray = newArray.filter((item) => !checker.includes(item));
    console.log(filterredArray);
```

Even though I run that, I still get the blank array as shown in the picture below at `index[0]`. What conditions should I put in the checker variable to check and remove the blank array?:

[image: Blank]

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected outcome is for the object to not contain the blank array shown. As you can see in the picture index[0] contains nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but your filtering will fail since `.includes` checks for object references.

So if you have

```
const newArray = [{}]

const checker = [null, undefined, [{}], {} ,[], ''];

const filteredArray = newArray.filter((item) => !checker.includes(item));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

the `filteredArray` will still contain `{}` as `{} === {}` evaluates to `false`.

To solve this you can use "deep equality" to compare the objects, e.g. using lodash

```
const filterredArray = newArray.filter((item) => !checker.some(check => _.isEqual(check, item)));
```

Comment: I'll try that. Basically I want that blank array off my state.

Comment: It worked. I can't believe I found out lodash just now. DAAAMNN!!!